# Error on RubyGem FPM

Tags: rubygems, grafana

I'm trying [Grafana](https://github.com/grafana/grafana) and I'm following its [instructions](http://docs.grafana.org/project/building_from_source/) in order to build it from source.

Although, when I get to the part of creating optimized release packages, after installing FPM (v.1.4.0), I keep getting the same error:

```
$ fpm
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- ffi (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/fpm-1.4.0/lib/fpm/util.rb:3
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/fpm-1.4.0/lib/fpm/package.rb:2
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/fpm-1.4.0/lib/fpm.rb:3
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/fpm-1.4.0/bin/fpm:5
    from /usr/bin/fpm:19:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/fpm:19
```

Any idea on what it may be? I'm on a RedHat EL6 64 bit machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of searching and lots of trial and error, I came to find a solution for my problem through the command below:

**gem install --http_proxy http://username:password@proxy fpm**

The problem was on how to correctly use the *gem* command in order to go around my company's proxy and fetch all of FPM's dependencies.